# iterating only through the files names in a directory using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to only access the file names in a directory?

```
>> files = dir('*.png');
>> disp(class(dir('*.png')))
struct
>> fields

fields = 

    'name'
    'date'
    'bytes'
    'isdir'
    'datenum'

>> for i=1:numel(fields)
files.(fields{i}.name)
end
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

>> for i=1:numel(fields)
files.(fields{i}).name
end
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 11 results.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File names are in the field `names` of the struct array returned by [`dir`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html). So:

```
files = dir('*.png');
for k = 1:numel(files)
    f = files(k).name; % f contains the name of each file
end
```

Comment: An alternative to the for loop is to extract straight into a cell array by using `names={files.name};` Depending on what you need to iterate over the files for you can then use _cellfun_ to loop through each of the file names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ls` like this

```
list=ls('*.png');
for ii=1:size(list,1)
  s = strtrim(list(ii,:)); % a string containing the name of each file
end
```

`ls` works with `chars` instead of `cells`.